# Dynamic frontogenesis derivation

Tags: meteorology, temperature, mathematics

On page 142 of Lackmann's *Midlatitude Synoptic Meteorology*, Equation 6.7 gives the derivative of the Boussinesq buoyancy $b = \frac{g \theta'}{\theta_0 (z)}$ (perturbation potential temperature $\theta'$ and base state $\theta_0 (z)$) as

\begin{equation}
\frac{db}{dt}
= -w \frac{g}{\theta_{00}} \frac{d \theta_0}{dz}
\end{equation}

where $\theta_{00}$ is the base state potential temperature $\theta_0 (z)$ at $z = 0$. While I understand this to be an application of the chain rule

\begin{equation}
\frac{db}{dt}
= \frac{\partial z}{\partial t} \frac{\partial \theta_0}{\partial z} \frac{\partial b}{\partial \theta_0},
\end{equation}

I am unable to see why

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial b}{\partial \theta_0}
= - \frac{g}{\theta_{00}}
\end{equation}

when I instead would expect

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial b}{\partial \theta_0}
= - \frac{g \theta'}{\theta_0^2 (z)}.
\end{equation}

Any help would be much appreciated!